# Copy Background color from Master sheet to worksheet - not the contents

Tags: excel, superuser

I wonder if anyone can help, I'm a noob when it comes to excel. I have to create a speadsheet which will be used in Datacenter management and hardware tracking, so what I've done is created a master worksheet and a sheet per rack, what I need to achieve is when a cell on master sheet is filled with a background color (grey) it then changes the color on the corresponding worksheet. Not sure how much sense that makes :)

Master B2:B25 to worksheet 1 B4:B27.. 
Master D2:D25 to worksheet 2 B4:B27..
Master E2:E25 to worksheet 3 B4:B27..etc

I can't use copy because it copies the contents of the cell, which I won't want, only the background color.

Comment: Just a quick additional note: the reason I need color is because the contents of the two cells will be different and the rack space is calculated on cells by color.

Comment: What is your code so far? Where are you stuck? If this is not about code, you are in the wrong place. Post on SuperUser instead.

Comment: Sorry new to this site, do I get rid of the vba tag and put in superuser?

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
    Range("J11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

above will copy formats. BTW this came straight from the macro recorder, you should the macro recorder first

Could also use below

```
    Range("J12").Interior.Color = Range("J11").Interior.Color
```